# Bundle install fails on debugger on Mavericks due to missing method.h

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, bundle, rbenv

So a disclaimer up front:
I'm rather new to rails development.

The situation is:

- I am using rbenv with ruby version 2.0.0-p247.
- which ruby outputs: $HOME/.rbenv/shims/ruby
- I did install the Mavericks X-Code command line tools using the .pkg file in the downloaded dmg file.

Running "gem install debugger" works fine...however, running "bundle install" fails!

The thing that I don't understand is:
In the gem_make.out file I find that the ruby version used to execute extconf.rb is:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

which is **not** the linked rbenv version I have installed.

Furthermore checking into debuggers "mkmf.log" I figured that the file **"method.h"** wasn't found.
In the log file there is a cascade of subdirectory listings going into the guts of the system and I have to admit that I stopped there.

The central question is:
**Why is bundle install ending up in the system ruby bin instead of the rbenv one?**

**UPDATE**

It is resolved...the problem is the gem_path. The bundler installed gems into the rbenv ruby version...the gempath in my app pointed at ~/.gem at the first location. Renaming/removing the ~/.gem directory lead to the app's gempath pointing toward the rbenv gems.

The Reason why bundle install ended in the system ruby directory is the following:
At ~/.gem there was no debugger installed...but in that directory the system gem path was set yet again to a different path...the system ruby gem path.
It seems like the app's gempath pointed into the home directory and from there it redirected towards the systems gem path.

Well...quite obvious if you know it...i hope it helps somebody!

Comment: Is rbenv in your PATH?

Comment: Yes, "which ruby" points to the rbenv ruby version, which I had to prepend to my path.

Comment: I´m not sure why your setup does not work but I would recommend installing [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and [rvm](http://rvm.io/) instead of rbenv. I just did a fresh install on Maverics and it was a very simple and painless install.